# linux kernel module memory layout under NUMA

Tags: linux-kernel

if I have static data in the module like
`static int some_param` and I run on a multi-cpu machine with NUMA. where the data segment will be located? I read that on NUMA the text might be replicated to avoid the latency of accessing a far memory node, but data is not possible to replicate as it is not a read only. 
where is the module itself loaded? is it NUMA aware or it must be loaded to the predefined modules mapped area.

here are the references:
http://www.redhat.com/promo/summit/2008/downloads/pdf/Thursday/Mark_Wagner.pdf
http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~sergey/cs108/solaris_kernel_memory.pdf
http://halobates.de/memory.pdf

Comment: AFAIK the module will be loaded into the architecture-defined module virtual address space only. Also, citing things you've read helps everbody.

Comment: thanks Jonathon references added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the OS. If you are using Linux a "First Touch" policy will be applied. This means all the data of you program will be allocated on a node close to the one containing the CPU on which your program is running.

Logically your program will see a unique shared memory. In a lower lever the OS may allocate the data on different NUMA node causing some performance issues.

It depends on you if you want to write a NUMA-aware code to avoid NUMA latency and contention. Although some Linux distribution are already implementing some NUMA balancing features. (e.g. [Automatic NUMA Balancing](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Tuning_and_Optimization_Guide/sect-Virtualization_Tuning_Optimization_Guide-NUMA-Auto_NUMA_Balancing.html))